# Magento configurable products and associated products

Tags: magento

I have an issue when I add a new configurable product, then try to add associated products
to this the associated products do not appear.
Also if I go into edit the product it prompts to Select Configurable Attributes
even though the type is already a configurable product.
The attribute set is applicable to all product types.

Seems like the JavaScript to add the simple products to the configurable is not firing
and when I save the product, because there are no options added to the attribute it prompts me
to choose an attribute set again.

Any help would be great

Comment: see what happens in the browser console - maybe U r right and some JS fails to load or sth - console is a good place to start investigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankyou for the reply, it appears that the script folder was missing, i download the latest version and upload the files to the correct path and issue resolved, this link helped 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/prem../viewthread/914919/#t477173 
thanks for your help.